# Modrewrite to lighttpd, AIS: Adaptive Image Style

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7, lighttpd

I've the following .htaccess:

```
# AIS: Adaptive Image Style
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/files/styles/adaptive/(.+)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/modules/image/sample.png
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ais=([a-z0-9-_]+)
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/files/styles/adaptive/(.+)$ $1/files/styles/%1/$2[R=302,L]
```

how can I convert it to lighttpd?

Answer (score 0):

```
$HTTP["cookie"] =~ "ais=([a-z0-9-_]+)" {
  url.rewrite = ( "^(.+)/files/styles/adaptive/(.+)$" => "$1/files/styles/%1/$2" )
}
```